# Phone location on call or SMS

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, native, whatsapp

I am an android applications developer. I just wanted to know that can we get the geo location of a phone number just by calling or sending an SMS to that number? Like in whatsapp, we can see the last seen time of the person, likewise can we get the last seen time with the exact last location. This is found in facebook messenger. I am just curious if it is possible using just a phone number.

Comment: you must have your web service to pass destination device location to your device.

Comment: Is it possible to get location with an IM message?

Comment: no, you cannot get location of instant messages

Comment: you can get location of device via sms or call only if you have web Service as mediator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45703/discussion-between-vjeta-and-jay)

Comment: ok, but if I am calling or messaging someone from my number, then can I get the location of the person whom I am calling or messaging

Answer (score 1):

Android apps that share current user(phone number) location identify there users by phone numbers, i think you already sent an SMS to Whatsup or Viber service before using it and you must put your phone number in your Facebook profile, those services can stock last known location of there users periodically (each 2 hours) or each time the user use this app in there servers and share it with other users check my detailed answer here [**https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714011/1889341**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714011/1889341)

Answer (score 0):

No, the call and sms data not contains position(as geo localiation) and Android is not able to get them on receiving call that i know.
The only way is to create a custom Service android that catch the event of outgoing call and send the position to your own API server on to register this event and work with it.

Whats app and facebook are not normal SMS message. Are response to a web service that contains custom data. The facebbok and whatsapp developer have created a data structure that aggregate the informations of geo localization to the message data.

Comment: Is it possible to get location with an IM message?

Comment: I think that depends by the protocol of every specific IM. If you implement a your personal solution it can be possible, sure.